# why is class integer automately returned 1

Tags: class, integer

I have a problem with my code.
My code make for a value game.

There are 2 items, each have value and weight and a ship have max weight content.
When I input those value the console returns 1.

Can somebody tell me why integer class return 1 and how to fix it?

```
public class Sort {

    static int knapsackLight(int value1, int weight1, int value2, int weight2, int maxW) {
        if (weight1 + weight2 <= maxW) return value1 + value2;
        else{
            int d1 = maxW - weight1;
            int d2 = maxW - weight2;
            if (d1>=0 && d2>=0){
                if (value1 >= value2) return value1;
                else return value2;
            }
            else if (d1>=0 && d2<0) return d1;
            else if (d2>=0 && d1<0) return d2;
        }
        return 0;
    }  

    public static void main(String[] a){
        int val1 = 5;
        int val2 = 9;
        int w1 = 10;
        int w2 = 6;
        int maxW = 7;

        System.out.println(knapsackLight(val1,w1,val2,w2,maxW));
    }
}
```

Comment: try with new values to "w2", "maxW" and "w1"

Answer (score 0):

1 is the correct answer for those values.

If *(weight1 + weight2 <= maxW)* is false *(10 + 6 > 7)*

*(d1>=0 && d2>=0)* is false because *d2* is smaller than *0 (-3)*.

So your are returning *d1* which is *maxW(7) - weight1(6) = 1*.

Comment: oh, I get it. how weird that I can not see my return.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You will get different return values as per input values. You can add debug statements before return value to check which condition is holding true value. e.g.

```
System.out.println("value1");
return value1;
...
...
System.out.println("value2");
return value2;
...
...
System.out.println("d1");
return d1;
...
...
System.out.println("d2");
return d2;
```